# Online - SharePoint Workflow 2010 always return "Canceled" as status

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

In my SharePoint Online site I have created a SharePoint 2010 Workflow that starts when items are created.

I've a list, where users insert new items, then a Workflow creates a Word document and saves it in another document libray. The Word template is set as model for the document library.

Users are in a specific SharePoint group called "Sales".

So this is my scenario with permission level of the "Sales" group:

SHAREPOINT SITE (Read)

-- LIST: DATA (Contribute)

-- DOCUMENT LIBRARY: CONTRACTS (Contribute)

-- LIST: TASKS (Contribute)

-- LIST: WORKFLOW HISTORY (Contribute)

Every time an users add an item in the "Data" list, the Workflow that is starting automatically returns "Canceled" as status.

If I check the details I can see "Access Denied" and a message asking to check for user permissions.

In my Workflow I've also set to save some messages during the execution, but in details page of the workflow I don't have these messages, just the error above.

My user, that is a Site Collection Administrator with Full Control on the site, can run the workflow without problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Try giving full control permission on workflow history list.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I've tried to give full control to "Sales" group on the Workflow History list, but workflow still returned "Canceled".

Answer (score 0):

May be group settings restricting other users to start workflow.
please try to change "Who can view the membership of the group?" setting to every one. Hope it will resolve your problem.

[image]